# Is there a JSONSchema for JSONSchema itself?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there a JSONSchema for JSONSchema itself? I am building a product that requires me to validate if the user has provided a valid JSONSchema. I did a lot of Googling but I can't seem to find an example.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what goes in the `$schema` keyword: one of:

- http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#
- http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#
- http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#
- http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
- https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema

...or perhaps a schema that extends one of those.

Comment: The `$schema` keyword identifies the type of schema being used, and the URI happens to in this case also be the `$id` of the associated meta-schema. The meta-schemas may be updated from time to time, and are informative only (do not form part of the specification).

Answer (score 0):

"JSONSchema for JSONSchema itself".

What you are you looking for is the metaschema.json

You can check https://json-schema.org/ and if you need a more language engineering perspective you can check this scientific paper https://epub.jku.at/obvulioa/content/pageview/6390647?query=berardinelli