validating json object matches a json schema object
I realize how meta this is, but I want to define a JSON schema, that lets users define a schema.  For example, the user could describe a field as an array of values. I'd like to be able to validate that the schema used to describe the field is a superset of an array schema object, ie it has the "name" field, an "items" list, etc.
Is there a JSON schema published that could be used to verify it matches the JSON-schema definition of an array?

Why don't you require the user-provided schema to be a valid JSON Schema?  The answer might be "JSON Schema is too complex for my users" (but perhaps those complexities exist for a reason) or "I want to restrict what schema functionality users can use" (if so, clarify better what your allowed functionality/restrictions are).  Please explain further and provide examples of the user-provided schema and content that matches the user-provided schema (e.g. an actual data array).

There are schemas for JSON Schema itself.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605684/is-there-a-jsonschema-for-jsonschema-itself and https://json-schema.org/specification#meta-schemas .  One specific metaschema (for validation) is https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/validation .

@MatthewFlaschen, the actual schema is going to be a superset of the json schema.  I'm going to extend it beyond just the array schema definition.

Yes it's possible.you can create your own dialect of JSON schema 2020-12 which can further constrain existing keywords or define completely new keywords.https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core#rfc.appendix.D   https://docs.json-everything.net/schema/vocabs/   you would also do well to join the https://json-schema.slack.com
